# High CPU when I use progressbar in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have such high CPU when I'm lauchnig page with 2 progressbar ...

I checked it , I deleted them and site was much faster.

This is snippet of my progressbar :

```
                    <progressbar class="progress-danger progress-striped active" value="procentValueEmail" name = "domains_emails_search">

                  <span class="badge badge-info-rev" n>
                      {{procentValueEmail | number:1}}%
                         </span>
                        </progressbar>
```

I'm using Angularjs, procentValueEmail is cosnstance value.

Any idea how can I use progressbar in Angualar without lags ?
My Lib

```
<script src="static/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html markup you have a class set 'active'. That class will cause redraws as it switches on animations which aren't visible.

```
<progressbar class="progress-danger progress-striped" value="procentValueEmail" name = "domains_emails_search">
```

Remove the class and you would not have the performance issue.